# how can adjust the columns to show the data according to query?

Tags: php, datatable

this is my query and it  works well

```
SELECT companies.name as name,services.id as service_id , services.Companie_Fk as companieId,services.desc as desk from services INNER JOIN companies ON services.Companie_Fk =companies.id;
```

And it shows to me this output and  that is right

[image]

This is my code for using the data table to show above results :

```
       <?php 
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
   $dbDetails = array( 
    'host' => 'localhost', 
    'user' => 'root', 
    'pass' => '', 
    'db'   => 'adsl'
    ); 
$table = 'services'; 
$primaryKey = 'id'; 
$columns = array( array( 'db' => 'desc', 'dt' => 0 ),array( 'db' => 'price', 'dt' => 1 ), 
array( 
'db'        => 'id',
'dt'        =>3, 
'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) { 
return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary btn-edit" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"> ویرایش </a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete ml-2" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"> حذف </a>'; 
} 
) 
); 
// Include SQL query processing class 
require '../ssp.class.php'; 
// Output data as json format 
echo json_encode( 
SSP::simple( $_GET, $dbDetails, $table, $primaryKey, $columns ));
```

now , How can I adjust the columns to show the data according to above query?

i'm using  ssp-class in this link :

[pastbin](http://pastebin.fr/99021)